# How long does Snare last if a creature does not escape the restrained effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The "Snare" spell lists its duration as 8 hours. However, it has some fairly unique wording near the end, providing that

> After the trap is triggered, the spell ends when no creature is restrained by it.

This sort of makes me think that the 8 hour duration is for an un-triggered trap, but that a triggered trap takes on a new duration (permanent, until no creature is restrained by it). Or, is it more likely that this simply means that the snare lasts up to 8 hours, unless earlier ended by a creature escaping the restraint?

Answer (score 9):

The duration is 8 hours or until the creature restrained by it escapes.

Earlier the description says:

> The creature is restrained there until the spell ends.
>
> A restrained creature can make a Dexterity saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success. Alternatively, the creature or someone else who can reach it can use an action to make an Intelligence (Arcana) check against your spell save DC. On a success, the restrained effect ends.

So it lasts 8 hours but this can be reduced if triggered and the creature either saves or escapes.

Comment: I do not think I adequately laid out the (very technical) argument in favor of reading Snare this way. I have created a new question, which more generally addresses the general phenomenon underlying this question, but which is independent of any snare-specific answer. Please do not mark as duplicate, it deserves separate consideration.